# Mimic the HttpForbiddenHandler Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

The HttpForbiddenHandler Class is sealed however I'd like to create a class that behaves like it. Something like this:

```
public class ForbiddenHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // do the 403 here somehow
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

How would I cause that 403 redirect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simply want to send the 403 status code:

```
context.Response.Status = "403 Forbidden";
```

Also, you might want to write some message to the client:

```
context.Response.Write("This is very much forbidden!");
```

If you wish to redirect the user to the 403 custom error page, configured in your web.config or machine.config, you should be able to do it like this:

```
throw new HttpException(403, "Forbidden");
```